# FASM: macro to display string

Tags: dos, fasm

I want to create macro in FASM, which could directly print string (int DOS) like this:

```
prints 'hey there!!!!'
```

I have written such code:

```
format MZ

use16
stack 0x100
entry _TEXT@16:_start

;
macro prints str
{
    call @f
    db str, 0x24

    @@:
        pop dx
        mov ah, 9
        int 0x21
}

segment _DATA@16 use16
    msg db 'hi!', 0xd, 0xa, 0x24

segment _TEXT@16 use16
    _start:
        push _DATA@16
        pop ds

        prints 'hi there))) !!!!'
        prints 'me'

        mov ax, 0x4c00
        int 0x21
    ret
```

The problem is: when I leave my _DATA@16 segment empty (without any variables) all is fine.
But when I define new variable in that segment some raw extra symbols begin to appear like this: http://board.flatassembler.net/files/err_758.png

So can you help me? where is my mistake?
Maybe I have chosen the wrong way to achieve that thing I want?
Help please....

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood it is because int 21h expects offset in _DATA@16 segment but not _CODE@16 segment. So, the easiest way - to use only one segment in program or just using .com files. Here is sample:

```
use16
org 0x100

macro prints [str*]
{
    pusha

    if str in <0xd, 0xa, 9>\
        | str eqtype ''

        call @f
        db str, 0x24

        @@:
            pop dx
    else
        mov dx, str
    end if

    mov ah, 9
    int 0x21

    popa
}

_start:
    prints 0xd, 0xa, 9
    prints 'hi!', 0xd, 0xa
    mov ax, msg
    prints ax, 0xd, 0xa
    prints msg

    int 0x20
ret

msg db 'hey there!', 0x24
```

It can accept strings directly, addresses of strings in registers and variables. 
It can also handle 3 special characters - 0xd (CR), 0xa (LF) and 9 (TAB).

If I find the way to display string directly in multi-segment programs, I will post the answer.

Comment: push cs/pop ds before the int 21h call.